# Как отключить загрузку видео для плееера videojs на сайте

Tags: javascript, видео

Подскажите пожалуйста. Пользуюсь плеером videojs. Минус в том, что когда загружается страница, начинает подгружаться и видео, в результате скорость загрузки страницы падает, что не очень хорошо сказывается на seo. Я знаю что для ютуба делают кнопку и только после нажатия на неё происходит загрузка. Можно ли такую кнопку сделать на videojs? Игде можно почитать и посмотреть конкретные примеры?
Вот код:

```html
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480" poster="../img/lessons/lesson_4/lesson_4.3/friendship_logo.jpg" data-setup="{}">
  <source src="../video_les/lesson_4/4.3.Poem_Are_We_Friends_mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <!-- <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type="video/webm" /> -->
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web 
    browser that <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video.min.js"></script>
<!-- Конец блока для вставки видео -->[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимно именно отсрочить загрузку видео, то для тега `video` замените атрибут на [`preload="metadata"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp)

Comment: сенкю вери мач!!!! вроде на 10 процентов производительность возрасла...

Comment: Можете, ещё поставить аргумент `none` тогда ещё быстрее будет... Но надо смотреть что в приоритете. Обычно если видео тегов на странице много, то запуск видео вешают на JS. А там только атрибут `poster` добавляют